# If click on a div, assign this url to the getJSON method.

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have an app that display headline news using an API. However I would like to make it so that if the user clicks on a certain div area, the url used on the getJSON method changes, and so do the displayed news.

What I'm doing, is assigning a class to the div after the click:

```
$(".block2").click(function(){
 $(this).addClass("selected");
  })
```

And then an if statement to check if the div has that class or not:

```
if ($(".block2").hasClass("selected")){

   var url= "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=buzzfeed&sortBy=top&apiKey=XXXX"

} else {

   var url= "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=XXXX";

  }
```

Why does this work, when I go to the HTML and add manually the class "selected" to the .block2 div but it doesn't using the click function? According to the console the class gets added. I think I have to re-call the getJSON function after I add the class maybe? But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Please show the full context of where your `if()` code is. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You have only two option and you want to choose your url with the selected block. I suggest you, when you add the class your block element set new url after then call your function.

```
var url = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=XXXX";

$(".block2").click(function(){
 $(this).addClass("selected");
 var url= "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=buzzfeed&sortBy=top&apiKey=XXXX";
})

getdatafromgetJSON();
```

and your options more than 2, adapt the below code to your project

```js
var base_url    = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?sortBy=top&apiKey=XXXX";
var request_url = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?sortBy=top&apiKey=XXXX&source=bbc-news";

$("div[class^='block']").on('click',function(){
    request_url = base_url+"&source="+$(this).data('site');
    $('div.last_url span').text(request_url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='last_url'><strong>Your Last Request Url: </strong><span>https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?sortBy=top&apiKey=XXXX&source=bbc-news</span></div><hr>

<div class='block-1' data-site='stackoverflow'>SO | Click me</div>
<div class='block-2' data-site='bbc-news'>BBC | Click me</div>
<div class='block-3' data-site='buzzfeed'>BuzzFeed | Click me</div>
```